# Как получить из строки массив?

Tags: массивы, json, php, javascript

На сервере массив типа:

```
[
    '28.01.2015' => [
        '03' => 2, 
        '02' => 4
    ]
]
```

был преобразован в строку с помощью функции `json_encode`.

Получилась строка:

```
{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}
```

Как теперь с помощью Javascript преобразовать эту строку в массив?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Вы это искали?

Answer (score 0):

```
array = eval( '(' + JSONText+ ')' );
```

Comment: Ох как это черевато, очень черевато. Если можно подменить JSONText.

    JSONText = 'alert("XSS");' //DONE

Comment: Заинтересовали, можно какой то пример, а то я в яве не особо.

Comment: @mrFlyer, самый [безобидный пример][1]

    var JSONText = 'document.body.innerHTML = ""'; 
    var array = eval( '(' + JSONText+ ')' );

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/5gch841s/

Comment: А как это может отразиться на третьего пользователя? То что изначальный пользователь делает с загруженной для него страницей - это его проблемы. Аналогично тому, что если бы я сохранил страницу гугла на комп и потом внес через блокнот свой код.

Или я что-то не понимаю?